# Salesforce CPQ: Product Setup scenario

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, app, cpq

I'm trying to setup the below product set up in salesforce CPQ.

Product: BAG

Now, I need to set up the price of this particular BAG product based on the Colour in the line editor.

For Ex: 
If the user selects below configurations in the line editor,

- Colour - White - $100
- Colour - Black - $110
- Colour - Blue - $120

the price should change dynamically for the product BAG.

One way is creating all these combinations as individual products/components and bundle it to choose under BAG. But when there are many combinations, we cannot create all of them as Individual Products/Components.

Comment: is the color an actual field on the quote line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this use case. I used Pricing Rule concept to dynamically change the price when the configuration attribute is selected.

Pricing Rule:

1. Rule Name: Price Change
2. Evaluation Order: 1
3. Evaluation Criteria - All

Pricing Conditions:

1. Target Object - Quote Line
2. Target field - Color__c (api name of the field I created in the Quote Line)
3. Operator - Equals
4. Type - Value
5. Value - Black

Pricing Actions:

Action 1:

1. Target Object - Quote Line
2. Target field - SBQQ__SpecialPriceType__c
3. Type - Value
4. Value - Custom

Action 2:

1. Target Object - Quote Line
2. Target field - SBQQ__SpecialPrice__c
3. Type - Value
4. Value - $110